# Chrome - children clip css3 rounded border?

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, clipping, css

Please see the following JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zScKW/

Notice that the child div clips the border of its parent. If I remove the border (but keep the rounded corners), the item clips as we would expect. Firefox 4 renders this markup as I expect, with the item clipped before the border starts. Chrome, however, does not clip the child until the border's outer edge is reached.

Who has this behavior correct, and is there a hack? I am fine with leaving it in chrome if it is a bug that will be fixed, but I will need to tweak the layout if it is rendering to spec in Chrome.

(please note before you vote to close, this is a different bug than the multiple threads about a firefox 3.5/Chrome bug which prevented items from being clipped at all by rounded borders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `child` element a radius of half the `border-radius` of its `parent`.

```
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zScKW/1/

Comment: One of those things that's so simple you wonder why you didn't think of it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually all you need to is add `position:relative` to the `child` element.

Answer (score 0):

I post related bug for it in http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=99364